# Python 3.4 and pySerial2.7 "Write to Serial Port?"

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am rather new to Python but am finding it quite useful.  I have a simple app that reads data from COM34 and stores it in a file, this works fine!!  I am now trying to write a simple command to the same COM34 port. When I follow the examples shown in numerous areas I get the following error...?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Projects_All/EmbeddedMasters/Firmware/Python/my_Serial.py", line 26, in <module>
port.write("hello")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
data = to_bytes(data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
import serial

addr = 'COM34'
baud = '3000000'
fname = 'my_test.dat'
fmode = 'w'
reps = 100
bufferVal = 256

with serial.Serial(addr,baud) as port, open(fname,fmode, bufferVal) as outf:
    print(port)
    print(outf)
#    header = "Is it writing to file?\n"
#    outf.write(header)
    for i in range(reps):
        x = port.readline()
        s = str(x)
        print(s)
        outf.write(s)
        outf.write('\n')
        outf.flush()
        port.write("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
port.write("hello".encode())

Answer (score 1):

I guess after 7 months you may have found your answer,
if no here is my suggestion

[How to Fix TypeError: an integer is required in python 3.4, pyserial 2.7 virtual serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895113/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-in-python-3-4-pyserial-2-7-virtual)

I used to have the same problem but I found the answer

```
outf.write(temp1.encode('utf-8'))<------- in your case
```

when Python assign the command .write IT MUST HAVE .endcode() or .encode('utf-8') or ('hex') or ('ascii') etc check this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings  and this one http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm