# How to Fix TypeError: an integer is required in python 3.4, pyserial 2.7 virtual serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, usb, pyserial

**EDITED**

Hello programmers Community,
I have some problems dealing with pyserial in Python 3.4
first I do not have serial ports so I have used "Virtual Serial Port Driver 7.2  by Eltima Software" to create virtual serial ports in pairs, which means that I can try to send and receive data from these ports, in my case I just create COM1 connected to COM2, then I installed Hercules SETUP utility by HW group to  monitor these serial ports,

so IN THEORY IF I SEND(write) DATA IN PYTHON I CAN SEE IT IN HERCULES AS THIS LINK SHOWS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DItyttmpRtY

I was trying to create my own code

```
def mInitizalise():
 set_ser = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=9600, 
                         parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                         stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                         bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                         timeout=1)
 set_ser.close()
 set_ser.open()
 if set_ser.isOpen():
     print ('Open: ' + set_ser.portstr)
     temp = input('Type what you want to send, hit enter:\r\n')
     set_ser.write(temp)
 set_ser.close()
```

Buy there is an error

```
>>> 
>>> Open: COM1
Type what you want to send, hit enter:
hello
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Downloads\SerialTest.py", line 25, in <module>
    ser.write(temp)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
    b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer is required
```

CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME

thanks beforehand for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figure it out, ----------tricky python--------- please pull me up, and check my other questions (with answers of course)

ok first assigning the serial port in a single line will not work as good as

```
#Method 1
set_ser = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=9600, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
```

writing it in this way

```
#Method 2
set_ser = serial.Serial()
set_ser.port="COM1"
set_ser.baudrate=9600
set_ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
set_ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
set_ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
set_ser.timeout=1
```

then USE method 2

second tricky part is this line

```
set_ser.write(temp1.encode('utf-8'))
```

when Python assign the command .write IT MUST HAVE .endcode() or .encode('utf-8') or ('hex') or ('ascii') etc check this link
https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings 
and this one
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm

now the final code is

```
def mSend():
  global set_ser, a
  set_ser = serial.Serial()
  set_ser.port="COM1"
  set_ser.baudrate=9600
  set_ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
  set_ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
  set_ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
  set_ser.timeout=1
  print ('Open: ' + set_ser.portstr)
  a = 0
  while a==0:
    temp = input('write open\r\r')
    if (temp == "open"):
      set_ser.close()
      set_ser.open()
      while set_ser.isOpen():
        temp1 = input('Type what you want to send, hit enter:\r\n')
        set_ser.write(temp1.encode('utf-8'))
        if (temp1 == "close"):
          set_ser.close()
          print ('\n\nClosed')
          a = 1
    elif (temp == "close"):
      set_ser.close()
      a = 1
    else:
      print ('unless you write open or close you can not move')
```

a button can call this function (this code) and it will open the serial port, send data until the user write "close"

Answer (score 1):

you are on windows ... that example is for linux

try `serial.Serial("COM1",9600)` (its probably not actually at "com1" you will need its actual comN name)

comm ports are enumerated as COM1..99 in windows you can see what it is in the device manager

Comment: thanks, is it fine my code, do you know any other example that I can use to write on the serial port?

Comment: what do you mean? does it work? there is not alot to it... what is the issue?

Comment: I mean It is no working, when I change the port to "COM3" it says The system cannot find the file specified.                                                            , I just want a simple example of pyserial for python 3.4, that I can try on my computer windows 8

Comment: You totally changed the question ... this was exactly the answer to your original question

Comment: well I did, I have changed the port to ("COM1",9600) as u say but I still have this error,  TypeError: an integer is required

Answer (score 0):

only put integer, so COM7 set_ser.port= 7 , but actually you must do N-1 so in device manager Windows you see COM7 => pythoncode: set_ser.port= 6